# Understanding some C++ code

Tags: c++

I dont understand the part: `struct tm * timeinfo;` what does this mean? Why there's a star there? Thanks!

```
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "The current date/time is: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All of that code is C compilable.  I re-tagged it - you'll get a wider audience that way.  If you were using C++ you probably would not code it that way.  The tm declaration for example would not need the struct keyword in C++

Comment: @Clifford: It's also valid C++. I don't see any need to re-tag it.

Comment: @DeadMG:  It is. I edited my comment to explain (hopefully).

Comment: @Clifford: I know what you mean. However, the OP is quite clear about what language he is using, and whilst his coding practices for C++ are terrible, it's not our job to tell him that he's using another language. He knows what language he is using. It's our job to tell him that his coding practices suck.

Comment: @DeadMG: given that he talks about a star, I don't think he knows which language he is using, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct tm * timeinfo;
```

It's declaring a variable *timeinfo* of type `struct tm*`. This is C-syntax.

In C++, you don't need to write `struct` keyword. Just `tm * timeinfo` is enough!

Answer (score 4):

If you really don't know how *pointers* are declared in C++, you need to do more reading than will fit into an answer here. The `*` declares `pointer to`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pointer in C/C++.  Pointer is a basic function of C language.

Answer (score 0):

localtime() returns a *pointer* to an internal copy of a tm structure.  struct tm* declares a pointer to a tm struct.